# yii rights extension rights.php

Tags: yii, rbac

I am trying to install yii rights and followed what the documentation says
but it shows an error "include(Rights.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
it is there... the extension is under protected/modules/rights and rights.php is under components.

```
'import'=>array('application.modules.rights.*',
    'application.modules.rights.components',
),
'modules'=>array(
    'rights'=>array(
'install'=>true,
        ),
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'class'=>'application.modules.rights.components.RWebUser'
    ),
'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.modules.rights.components.RDbAuthManager',
    ),
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using Rights? [Yii-Auth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth/) is way more up to date  and was written by the same author.

Comment: Oh didn't know. Thanks!